# assigning snmpget output to a variable

Tags: bash, shell

Can you help me assign the snmpget output to a variable and then write it to the RESULTS file.

```
#!/bin/sh

workingdir="/home/dperera/ping-tests" # LOG=$workingdir/RESULT.csv

infile=$workingdir/RTR_LIST # while read device

do

#$device sysName.0 > /dev/null  
#if [ "$?" = "0" ] ; then    
    rtr = snmpget -v2c -c xxxxx $device mib-2.47.1.1.1.1.11.1  >> $LOG
    echo "$device, $rtr" >> $LOG                    
#   fi
done < $infile
```

Comment: What specifically do you mean by `output` -- the standard output, standard error, both, return code?

Comment: What happens when you only try `echo "$rtr"` isntead of `echo "$device, $rtr" >> $LOG` ? Do you have your `rtr` variable value printed in your console ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [tee](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) for it, `tee` would write the output to both stdout and log file. Modify your command as followed would assign the output of `$(snmpget ...)` to `rtr`, and write to `$LOG` as well.

```
rtr=$(snmpget -v2c -c xxxxx $device mib-2.47.1.1.1.1.11.1 | tee -a $LOG)
```

Mind that `-a` for `tee` would allow the output append to the given `$LOG`, rather than overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

I bet the following command line returns you an error code :

```
rtr = snmpget -v2c -c xxxxx $device mib-2.47.1.1.1.1.11.1  >> $LOG
```

First, remember that in bash, you cannot let spaces before and after your `=` symbol. Plus, remember that you want the return value of the command, so you need to use the `$`.Therefore, this should work :

```
rtr=$(snmpget -v2c -c xxxxx $device mib-2.47.1.1.1.1.11.1)
```

After this, writing your variable into a log file can simply be done with :

```
echo rtr >> your.file
```

Did not try it by myself, but should be fine.
Hope it helped !

Comment: does not work and I get the following error.                         xxxx@ovmsn1[48] ./test.sh
./test.sh: syntax error at line 16: `rtr=$' unexpected
~